# Remove all special characters but keep dots and accents

Tags: php

I'm trying to remove all special characters from a string keeping dots and accents. I already got the accents working, how can I allow the dots?

My function.

```
function clean($string) {

   return preg_replace('/[^\p{L}0-9\-]/u', ' ', $string);// Removes special chars.

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a dot to your character group. `/[^\p{LN}\-.]/u` `<-- see the dot`